# Is it possible to create a Dot Net Nuke partial view for an MVC site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, dotnetnuke

I am looking at the posibility of integrating a third party component into our MVC-based site. The reason is that we want document handling and search features without taking the full job of implementing it from scratch.

I'm unsure about the way to proceed and I am wondering if any of you have any experience with Dot Net Nuke. Is it possible to run an instance of Dot Net Nuke in the cloud and create a partial view providing a document module(cms-like) and a search module?

Is there any other third party systems that are cloud compatible and provide an API for handling documents, security and full text search?

Comment: sharepoint online looks good option for you. obviously it is cloud based but not mvc based site but provides really good document management,search and out of the box web services for seamless integration. It is not free that's the only down part.